# Not able to add TTL in new DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, cloud

Not able to see Manage TTL section in new DynamoDB console. It was there in old console.

Old console -

[image]

New Console -

[image]

Any help which can guide me to the manage ttl section in new console?

The documentation still points or showcase old console -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html#time-to-live-ttl-how-to-enable-console

Answer (score 2):

As indicated at the bottom of the new console pages:

> Some features are not available yet in the preview of the new console. To access features still to be added to the preview, please revert to the current console.

You can revert temporarily to the old/current console, or you could use the awscli's [update-time-to-live](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/update-time-to-live.html) command.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of AWS CLI and old console, I was precisely looking for option in new console. Submitted feedback to AWS.

Comment: I think the answer is: it doesn’t exist, yet.